# iframe height "100% - X pixels"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'd like to cut the bottom area of an external iframe that I want to include on my site, within this frame there are links that I cannot modify and if I click them I go to another page that has a different size from the original.

I'd like to do something like `<iframe height:100%-20px />` (I know that there isn't a syntax like this but my goal is to reproduce that)

So, is there a way to hide tot pixels form the bottom of an iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `calc()` function in css.

It's usable from `IE10` onwards (`IE9` is a bit shaky).

You can do this:

```
iframe{
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

If `100%` height was `100px`, then it would come out as `80px` (Excuse the simplicity, my math is horrible).

You can learn more by looking at this link: [Uses for Calc()](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

Reference: [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    .outer {
        width:300px;
        height:290px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    <div class="outer">
        <iframe width="300" height="300"></iframe>
    </div>
```

if this doesn't help do you have a link ?

You could play with the css of both the outer div and iframe with borders etc to make it look perfect

Answer (score 0):

Here a live demo based on BeatAlex answer:

`Demo:` http://jsfiddle.net/a7y7V/